# Downloading all files from a site that uses a CDN

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, cdn

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. I am attempting to use python to download all "Contract Information Book" files from the Indiana Department of Transportation Website at this link: https://erms.indot.in.gov/viewdocs/Default.aspx

I had a script working that downloads all files from a website, but this site has a search function to get to the necessary files so the script does not work.I believe it uses a CDN or something similar. When you perform a search for all "Contract Information Book" types files and click on a "Download" button, it redirects you do a different url, such as "https://erms.indot.in.gov/viewdocs/View12.aspx?Id=6623040," which prompts a PDF download.

I used the following code to test downloading all documents based on ID ranges, but there are many other files outside of the Contract Information Books that I'm looking for, so this is not effective:

```
import os
import requests


url_template = "https://erms.indot.in.gov/viewdocs/View12.aspx?Id={id}"
folder = "INDOT Contracts"

start_id = 6623040
end_id = 6623050

for i in range(start_id, end_id+1):
    url = url_template.format(id=i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, f"file_{i}.pdf")
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Is there a way to download the files based on my search of "Contract Information Book" document type?

Thanks for any advice or tips!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to pull down the HTML could you parse the HTML to find the tag/attribute that houses the file you're trying to download?  Quick glance at the HTML and I saw an input field that had the file name and query param.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you clarify what you mean by file name and query parameters? The only identifier I'm able to find in the HTML is the ID and I'm struggling to connect that to the file type I'm looking for (Contract Information Book). Thanks again for the insight!

Comment: You can search for "Contract Information Book" without an ID.  The next page is a paginated table of contracts; results.aspx.  Within the HTML on results.aspx you can see some of the contract IDs.  You'll need to recreate the POST requests to get the subsequent pages though.  It's ugly, though the only way I can think of doing it.  an example is onclick="window.open(&#39;View12.aspx?Id=6676477&#39

Comment: Totally, this makes sense thank you! The issue I ran into is determine what are the numbers of the contract IDs. For example ID 6676477 may be a contract, but 6676478 (the next number) will be a completely different document. Unsure how I can pull all of the correct IDs...

Comment: Could you try parsing out the onclick function value via regex; something like =([0-9]{8))& ?